# Sonar Custom reports

Tags: sonarqube

I need to generate custom reports using Sonar sql server database data. The structure of the database is quite confusing me. How can I get below details of my project?
LoC(lines of code) 
Rule Compliance % 
Comment % 
Public Documented API % 
Security Violations 
Violations (excluding Info) 
Duplicated Line %

Once I get these details how can I stucture my report because root data is having many childs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably really want to use the web services to extract data, rather than reading from the database.  See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Services for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend to directly request database because it's not considered as an API. It deeply evolves over time.

There are currently two reporting plugins that generate PDF :

- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+PDF+Plugin (open-source + commercial edition)
- http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/reporting/report/ (commercial)

If you want to generate your own report, then you should implement a plugin or request web services from a dedicated application.