# Export custom sonarqube report

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Basically, what I want to achieve is very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742243/sonar-custom-reports)

However, the links in the answer are no longer available.

I'm very new to sonar, just set up the server and run some analysis example. I've been searching hours on how to export the test result rather than view it on the web.

Any guidance?

UPDATE:
I DON'T WANT PDF FILE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate PDF reports in SonarQube 6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006118/how-to-generate-pdf-reports-in-sonarqube-6-4)

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Thanks for the reply, I don't want a pdf file at all. What I need is a file that includes these result so I can then use these data and display it somewhere else (like on my personal website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you simply want raw data, to be formatted and displayed elsewhere, then what you're looking for is the [web services](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api). I've linked to [SonarCloud](https://sonarcloud.io), but you'll find the link to the Web API documentation relevant to your version in footer of each page served by your SonarQube instance.